# How to reduce current without affecting voltage for powering a fan?

Tags: current, amplifier, amperage, fan

So I have a **12 v 1 amp** power supply. I want to convert the current **from 1 amp to 0.08 amp and keep the voltage the same**. This is for a power a brushless fan; **specs 12 v 0.08 amp**. I am not sure how to do this. If anyone can help, I would appreciate it a lot.

Thank you

Comment: Thought experiment: How would you convert the 6 A lighting circuit in your house to power a lamp that only needs 0.2 A? (Assume that the light is the correct voltage for your house.)

Comment: if you want 80 mA to flow in a 12 V circuit, then you have to present a 150 ohm load to the 12 V power supply ....  I strongly suspect that the brushless fan already presents itself as a 150 ohm load

Answer (score 3):

You don't need to *"convert 1 A to 0.08 A".*

1 A is the MAXIMUM current that this power supply can provide.

If a car can get to a MAXIMUM of 100 mph, you don't need a "converter" to have this car cruising at 50 mph.

If you connect your 12V 1A supply to a load that needs 12 V, 0.08 A, the load will use **only the 0.08** that it needs.

But, beware: some power supplies need a *minimum* load to achieve the correct output voltage.

Comment: Thank you for clearing that up